# Is there any way to use iBooks author like pages/numbers/keynote on icloud?

Tags: mac, icloud, ibooks-author, google-apps, ibook

I use iBook author for my school projects and need to collaborate with my group members. Is there any way we can do so like using icloud or google drive? 
It will be very helpful if it can display who's typing what in real time like google drive/ icould.

Thanks

Comment: collaboration you will have alway some sync Problem with iCould GoogleDrive or Dropbox. You can store the File in an Online Service, but collabortion in Timeslots. This is afak the best way.

Answer (score 1):

No. This is not yet possible.

Use dropbox or something similar instead.

You can ask for new features via:

http://www.apple.com/feedback